# How to change title page stuff?

Tags: titles

This is the code part of the title (if you need me to put in all the code, let me know). I need to pass the one framed in red, up, to the left side of the logo, in the central part.

```
\def \@titlepage {
    \begin{titlepage}
    
    % Make the logo
    \makeatletter
    \centering\hbox{\hspace{30.0em}\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{\@logo}\par }
    
    % Make the title
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\LARGE \@title\par}
    
    % Some space, then the author, then the school and university
    % name
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    {\large \@author \par}\vspace{0.45cm}
    {\footnotesize \@schoolname \\ \vspace{0.25cm} \@collegename \\  \vspace{0.25cm}  \@universityname \par}
    
    % Some space and the submission statement
    \vspace{2.5cm}
    {\footnotesize \submissionStatement \par}
    
    % Print out the supervisor
    \vspace{1cm}
    \printSupervisor
    
    % Then the fancy date!
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\footnotesize \@date \par}
    
    \end{titlepage}
}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Please add a minimum  code that shows the above output, starting with `\documentclass{  ... `  and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I downloaded this code from overleaf: https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-lincoln-computer-science-thesis-template-unofficial/vdbphtsnwdqv . The file it compiles is called "main" and where the code is "lincolncthesis". There are 2 ways to make the title: "title first" or "logo first", I took the one that says "logo first"

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: I fixed it, thanks

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I tried to do it, but I don't know how to make it compile, because the codes are distributed in folders, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this

[image: a]

put this code before `\begin{document}`

```
\makeatletter
\def \@altTitlePage {%
    \begin{titlepage}       

        \makeatletter
        \begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
            {\footnotesize\centering
                \hspace{0.35\textwidth} \@schoolname \\ \vspace{0.25cm}
                \hspace{0.35\textwidth}\@collegename \\  \vspace{0.25cm} 
                \hspace{0.35\textwidth}\@universityname\\ }
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth} 
        \includegraphics[height=1.0in]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}  

        \vspace{2cm}\centering
        {\LARGE \@title\par}
        
        % Some space, then the author, then the school and university
        % name
        \vspace{1.5cm}
        {\large \@author \par}\vspace{0.45cm}
                
        % Some space and the submission statement
        \vspace{2.5cm}
        {\footnotesize \submissionStatement \par}
        
        % Print out the supervisor
        \vspace{1cm}
        \printSupervisor
        
        % Then the fancy date!
        \vspace{1cm}
        {\footnotesize \@date \par}
        
    \end{titlepage}
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: OMG! Dude, you are awesome, thank you!